# How do you verify that the indicated function is a solution of the given differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

My textbook gives the following problem, but I have never seen an integral like this before. After looking it up, I see it is a non-elementary integral. I emailed my professor and he told me that there is not a simple expression for the solution, but that there is a power series solution.

With that being said, I still have no clue how to use that to solve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Question:**

Use (12) to verify that the indicated function is a solution of the given differential equation. Assume an appropriate interval $I$ of definition of each solution.

**Statement 12:**

The derivative form of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that F is differentiable on $(a, b)$ and

$$
F'(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{x} g(t) dt = g(x)
$$

**Problem**:
$$
x \frac{dy}{dx} - 3xy = 1 ; \qquad y = e^{3x} \int_{1}^{x} \frac{e^{-3t}}{t}dt
$$

Comment: What do you get when you substitute the alleged solution for $y$ in the differential equation, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to differentiate the integral?

Comment: Hint: $y=e^{3x}F(x)$ (where $F(x)$ is that integral), $y'=3y+e^{3x}F'.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah thank you! Does this look right? I ended up getting: $$y=e^{3 x} \int_1^x \frac{e^{-3 t}}{t} d t$$ and 
$$ y^{\prime}=3 e^{3 x} \cdot \int_1^x \frac{e^{-3 t}}{t} d t+\frac{1}{x} $$

Comment: Yes, so $xy'=3xy+1,$ and you are done!